# How to implement a key-value pair with variability in the key

Tags: java, treemap, comparable

I'm writing some code to de-duplicate data based on 2 fields:

1. A string of characters, we'll call this the UMI
2. An array of integers

I've created a POJO to hold this data and work as key for a `TreeMap`. The full set of data is held in the value - this way I only keep relevant data in memory.

However, the next requirement is to have variability in the UMI AND the integers. For example, the following two pieces of data would be considered duplicates based on the UMI having a variability(mismatch) of 1.

a. "AAA", [200,300]

b. "ABA", [200,300]

Similarly, the following would be considered duplicates based on the integer array, given a mismatch allowance of 2.

a. "AAA", [201,300]

b. "AAA", [203,300]

My current attempt has been to make this POJO implement the `Comparable` interface, and attempt to work the `compareTo` method to take into account the variability:

```
public class UMIPrimoKey implements Comparable<UMIPrimoKey> {

    private final String UMI;
    private final int[] ints;
    private final int umiMisMatch;
    private final int posMisMatch;

    public UMIPrimoKey(String UMI, int[] ints, int umiMisMatch, int posMisMatch) {
        this.UMI = UMI;
        this.ints = ints;
        this.umiMisMatch = umiMisMatch;
        this.posMisMatch = posMisMatch;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(UMIPrimoKey o) {
        if (!Arrays.equals(ints, o.ints)) {
            if (ints.length == o.ints.length) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
                    if (Math.abs(ints[i] - o.ints[i]) > posMisMatch) {
                        return -1;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        if (XsamStringUtils.numberOfDifferences(UMI, o.UMI) <= umiMisMatch) {
            return 0;
        }

        return 1;
    }
}
```

`XsamStringUtils.numberOfDifferences` is just a simple static method to count the number of differences between the two UMIs.

I return -1 if any two integers from the array have a difference greater than the allowed mismatches (`posMisMatch`). 0 is returned if the integers are allowed, and the number of mismatches in the UMI is less than the allowed amount, specified by `umiMisMatch`.

Otherwise, 1 is returned as the UMIs don't match.

I've then used this in a `TreeMap` which takes into account the `compareTo` method.

This works in my unit tests, with small numbers of `UMIPrimoKey`s added to it, but I'm getting some strange results when running the completed program. It's probably due to the rules for the method outlined here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html but i'm finding it hard to adapt the code to take the rules into account.

Any direction is appreciated, thanks for reading!

Comment: What are the strange results?

Comment: Mainly, i'm adding keys to the map, then it's returning null when i'm trying to retrieve it again. I'm using the same data to search the map, and never removing any keys from the map.

Comment: Fundamentally, your criteria will fail a transitive test. Your current implementation will also fail because if A.compareTo(B) can return -1, and B.compareTo(A) can also return -1. If A<B then B>A.

Comment: Thanks matt, that clicked and I've changed the compareTo to reflect this.

Comment: Also, your goal is flawed.  You say UMI's of 'AAA' and 'ABA' are considered the same, because they are close enough.  But then 'ABA' and ABB' should be the same, and 'ABB' and 'BBB' should be the same, too.  But certainly 'AAA' and 'BBB' are not the same.  Equality should be transitive or you're going to get unpredictable results.

Comment: @Zag perhaps my explanation was not clear. It's just a simple String comparison using a number of mismatches - the hamming distance between the strings: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance

Comment: @Sam You were clear.  Perhaps I wasn't.  If your equality test is not transitive, it won't work.  You consider AAA and ABA to be equal because the hamming distance is only 1.  Therefore, I assume you consider ABA and ABB to be equal, for the same reason.  And ABB and BBB are then equal, as well.  By the transitive property of equality, which is assumed in the key of a TreeSet, you now need to consider AAA and BBB to be equal, since there is a chain of equality from one to the other.  Since they aren't, your tree possibly won't find the element after a tree rebalancing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) of compareTo:

> The implementor must ensure sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x)) for all x and y. (This implies that x.compareTo(y) must throw an exception iff y.compareTo(x) throws an exception.)
>
> The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive: (x.compareTo(y)>0 && y.compareTo(z)>0) implies x.compareTo(z)>0.
>
> Finally, the implementor must ensure that x.compareTo(y)==0 implies that sgn(x.compareTo(z)) == sgn(y.compareTo(z)), for all z.

I think that's not true to your code, and that could cause problems with the get function not finding your entry

Comment: This was the answer, I had to make sure I had criteria which ensure correct ordering. I ended up checking equality using my original parameter (returning 0). If not, I returned 1 or -1 depending on hashcode.